# Include ranking information in flairs

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flair

When you use [flairs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair), people that see them might not be particularly familiar with the meaning of badges, and whether "280k reputation is a lot or it's a mediocre thing".

So, I think it's appropriate to add some ranking information there - for example the one recently added to the profile "Top X % this quarter". Perhaps include the month and all-time data. Or even a a non-percentage rank for the top 500 users (ranked 89).

Another thing might be to add tag-relevant ranking. For example: "Ranked 5th in C#".

That's a lot of information to fit in the small flair, so the most relevant should be picked.

Update: [This StackUser app](https://stackapps.com/questions/1578/sorep-v2-ranked-flair-take-2) was suggested, but unfortunately it does not display up-to-date information (30k difference with my actual reputation)

Comment: This feature exists on some flair on StackApps.com.

Comment: @jjnguy could you give a link?

Comment: This is what you are looking for I believe: http://stackapps.com/questions/1578/sorep-v2-ranked-flair-take-2

Comment: @jjnguy unfortunately the information there is rather outdated. It shows me with 60k, and I have 95k